# Using smartmontools to check on Intel RAID arrays

Tags: windows-7, raid

I have a Windows 7 box with a two-drive RAID 0 array created using the motherboard's SATA controller (Intel ICH8/9). Since I can't access the SMART status of the drives in it (because they are abstracted as just one drive), I installed smartmontools to do so. Sure enough, if I do:

```
smartctl -a /dev/csmi0,0
```

It shows me the SMART status of one of the drives... but I don't know how to access the status of the other one. If I do:

```
smartctl -a /dev/csmi1,0
Smartctl open device: /dev/csmi1,0 failed: \\.\Scsi1:: access denied
```

And the same if I do "/dev/csmi2,0", 3,0, etc. And if I do:

```
smartctl -a /dev/csmi0,1
Smartctl open device: /dev/csmi0,1 failed: No device on port 1
```

What would be the right syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: I was told in the smartmontools mailing list that the second syntax was the right one, i.e.:

```
smartctl -a /dev/csmi0,1
```

The only problem is that the SATA devices aren't necessarily connected in order: maybe one drive is in "0", the next one in "4", etc.. Sure enough, in my case doing:

```
smartctl -a /dev/csmi0,4
```

Got the data for the other drive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **--scan** option to show the list of devices:

```
c:\>smartctl --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
/dev/sdc -d scsi # /dev/sdc, SCSI device
/dev/csmi0,0 -d ata # /dev/csmi0,0, ATA device
/dev/csmi0,2 -d ata # /dev/csmi0,2, ATA device
/dev/csmi0,3 -d ata # /dev/csmi0,3, ATA device
/dev/csmi0,4 -d ata # /dev/csmi0,4, ATA device
/dev/csmi0,5 -d ata # /dev/csmi0,5, ATA device
```

As you've correctly noted, the last number corresponds to the SATA port your device is connected to.